# Preventing Auto open And Workbook Open Events From Running in vba

Tags: vba, excel, events

I want to open a XLSM file in my vba code, but when I do it all the VBA scripts, or events open. So I just want to open, take 2 cells and close the file. Can anybody help me?

```
Sub meta1()
    Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlw As Excel.Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Data1 = InputBox("Escreve a data do nome do arquivo da seguinte forma: 2015-07-26")
        var1 = "blablabla" + Data1 + ".xlsm"
        var2 = "Blablabla" + Data1 + ".xlsm"

        Set xlw = xl.Workbooks.Open(var1)
        xlw.Sheets("APOIO").Select

        cont1 = Workbooks(var2).Worksheets("APOIO").Cells(61, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        cont2 = Workbooks(var2).Worksheets("APOIO").Cells(92, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        cont3 = Workbooks(var2).Worksheets("APOIO").Cells(26, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        xlw.Close False
        Set xlw = Nothing
        Set xl = Nothing
        cmgeral1 = Cells(61, cont1)
        conversão = Cells(92, cont2)
        derivacao = Cells(26, cont3)
```

Comment: Try setting `xl.EnableEvents = False` before opening the workbook.  Don't forget to set it back to `True` right after!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested:

```
Option Explicit

Sub preventEvents()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Workbooks.Open "FileName.xlsm"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```